Mocha unit test for React state variable change
I want to write a Mocha unit test for the react state variable changes.
For example,
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';

const RefillComponent = () => {

  const [refillResult, setRefillResult] = useState({
    status: 'notStarted',
    successfulIds: [],
    failedIds: [],
  });

  const onRequestRefills = async () => {
      const response = await MyAPICall(list);
      const failedIds = response?.failedIds || [];
      const successfulIds = response?.successfulIds || [];
      setRefillResult({
        status: failedIds.length > 0 ? 'failed' : 'success',
        failedIds,
        successfulIds,
      });
    }
  };

  const failedNotification = () => {
    return (
        <div>API request failed</div>
    );
  };
    
  return (
      <div>
        
        {(refillResult.status === 'failed') && failedNotification()}
            
      </div>
  );

};


export default RefillComponent;


I want to write the unit test when refillResult.status === 'failed' the text API request failed
should be displayed.
How can I write the unit test for the UI change when the state variable changes?
